# I would like to have several tag wiki edits reviewed

Tags: support, tags, suggested-edits, tag-wikis

I have several tag wiki edits pending for a week, I was wondering what is the review process for them?

Here are the suggested edits:

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/227988
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/227989
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/228021
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/228022

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same way as for regular suggested edits, i.e. via the [Suggested Edits review queue](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/). However, users need [5000 reputation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) to approve suggested edits to tag wikis; much more than the 2000 for regular Q&A posts. Therefore, those edits take much longer to be reviewed, see e.g. [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/1339590/suggested-edits-with-review-time) for comparison. (Some regular Q&A edits take or seem to take a long time too, because they're audits, or because the post author overrode a review outcome.)